# Javascript module pattern with Ajax callback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mongodb

I have writing a website that has several categories for which the data has to be pulled from the mongo database. So far i had written plan ajax calls but since this requirement need me to keep using the same ajax calls for variety of things i have begun to think about reusable code/patterns. I am a newbie to Javascript module patterns but so far what i read and understood , looks like the Revealing module pattern might be a good start for me rather than getting too much confused with rest of the object oriented stuff.

I know there are a lot of links , docs available in SOF and internet but i really could not get the direct answer for my simple requirement to start with so that i take it to the next level with what understand.

I have written a testing code here...

```
var myApp = new function () {

    var Var1 = [];

    getData = function (sendData) {

        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: URL,
            data: sendData,
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (results) {}
        });

    };

    getOffers = function (sendData) {
        getData(sendData);
    };

    return {
        getOffers: getOffers
    };

}();
```

getData is kept private to pull records from database and getOffers is public that call from outside as i understand. But, how do i get the success return of my ajax call outside of them ?

What i want to achieve is have an easy method to call my functions like below ..

```
myApp.getOffers({
    'showData': 1,
    'myLocation': "Location1",
    'clientID': "Client1"
});

myApp.getOffers({
    'showData': 1,
    'myLocation': "Location2",
    'clientID': "Client2"
});
```

that fetches data from my mongodb so that i can alter them based on my requirement. Each of them when returned values , i would manipulate to show them in diff Div's so that action need to be outside of my definition as these are not static.

How do i achieve it since it works when i return something from the function directly but when it has to return from ajax it does not due to the callback i have to write. But how is this generally written so that we can reuse the code and alter sending variety of fields with a simplest approach ?

Please alter this code so that i understand it better and start with something very basic to suit my requirement. OR send me few links that really explains my basics.

Also, I stick to ajax "POST" method for myApp for a reason i think is that when a "GET" method is used, users knowing what variable i pass(from its source-code) can directly send them as action.php?variable=1&variable=2. How do i avoid it if i can use GET method safely ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But, how do i get the success return of my ajax call outside of them?

Make `getOffers` return the jqXHR `getData` returns like below -

```
var myApp = (function () {

    var Var1 = [];

    var getData = function (sendData) {

        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: URL,
            data: sendData,
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (results) {}
        });

    };

    var getOffers = function (sendData) {
        // return the jqXHR returned by getData
        return getData(sendData);
    };

    return {
        getOffers: getOffers
    };

})();
```

The `jqXHR` object returned by `$.ajax({})` is a `Promise` -
When you get a success response for the Ajax request - you can attach a success handler like this - outside of your ajax request

```
myApp.getOffers({
    'showData': 1,
    'myLocation': "Location1",
    'clientID': "Client1"
}).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    // work with DOM here
});
```

More on Jquery Deferreds/Promises [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wrangle-async-tasks-with-jquery-promises--net-24135) -

Also you made `getData`, `getOffers` global by missing `var` in front during the declaration.

As per your comment on using `POST` instead of `GET`, the general rule of thumb is - `GET` is for retrieval of data, POST for saving - just because you use `POST` that does not mean some one can not sniff the data you are sending, it is just part of request body instead of the request URL. If you think the data you are sending is really sensitive, you should look into enabling `SSL(HTTPS)` for your app.

Comment: `getOffers()` would also need to return the return value from `getData()` for the promise to returned out to where you're trying to use it.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, updated my answer to be clear - Thanks

Comment: Thanks @JohnbabuKoppolu , that works. I understand jqXHR method now though i heard about the promise and callback for this requirement, i just could not get it working in the way i wanted it to be, to start with. This helps. Does anyone know of the answer for choosing GET vs. POST method ? How do we avoid anyone passing a 'GET' call to our backend script to retrieve data without going through the front-end scripts ?

Comment: Good solution, thanks!  You actually don't need the getOffers() function at all though, you can simply return { getOffers: getData } since getData is already returning that jqXHR object.